# C# disable viewstate but still use ViewState["item"]

Tags: c#, .net, viewstate

Is this possible, I've set  in webconfig file. 
However, couple web controls use ViewState["item"].ToString(), which now throw the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've tried just setting EnableViewState="true" in the header of the web control, but still get the same error. Is there any way around this?

Comment: check if it is not null?

Comment: Chris, you're calling .ToString() on a null object becuase your viewstats is disabled. Check to see if it's null first - which you should do anyway - then figure out how to get selective viewstate going.

Comment: Hello, am using .Net 4 Framework. How do you get a selective viewstate when turn off at webconfig level? again is this possible ? cheers

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1378945.aspx/1

You need to turn it on in the header of the page, not the control.

EDIT: According to http://forums.asp.net/t/1536937.aspx/1 you might need to enable it at the web.config level and disable it for each page where you don't want it.

Comment: I've tried this aswell, but still comes up with the same error

Answer (score 0):

If the ViewState["Item"] has never been set then when you are calling

ViewState["Item"].ToString();

you are effectively calling null.ToString();

so you need to check for null first - or else alway set it.

You could use something like:

```
var item = ViewState["Item"];
string s = item == null ? string.Empty() : item.ToString();
```